# Finding Writeable Remaining Space

Tags: disk-usage

I work for an organization where we employees are alloted separate space on a remote server.

I SSH to that server, and the using **du** I get to know that free space shown is around 2 GB.
But not all can be written by me.

Is there any way by which I can know the **writeable** free space?

Comment: Is your system using quotas?  In that case `quota -v` or some variation usually works.  Also, did you mean `df` instead of `du`?

Comment: @jw013 You should post this as an answer, it's likely the right answer, and even if it isn't it'll be helpful to future visitors in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Is your remote server using quotas? In that case `quota -v` or some variation usually works. Also, did you mean `df` instead of `du`?  `df` reports free disk space, while `du` reports file space usage.

Comment: I'm not able to run the `quota -v` command, says command not found. I meant to say `df` , but its not giving proper results for me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`du` is for showing the used space. Try [`df`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df), e.g.

```
$ df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs           60G   40G   18G  70% /
/dev/sda6        20G  9.2G   11G  46% /home
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I've tried `df`, but it doesnt give proper results for my workspace computer, somewhere the infosec group has done some settings, which I am not able to detect.

Answer (score 0):

Other than quotas (which it seems are not in use here), the only other reservation of space (which would limit how much you can write) is the space reserved for the root user by the filesystem. I think that this can only be discovered using `tune2fs` (which only root can use), but the default is 5%.